# How to calculate night shift in an Access DB using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with Inbounddatum1, Inbounddatum2, Timeinterval fields and I want to calculate summary of intervals based on shifts as showed below. Since night shift starts at 10:00 PM and ends at 6:00 AM, i couldn't find a proper way of showing it in the query. Could you help about the query? Thanks in advance.

```
Inbounddatum1          Inbounddatum2         Timeinterval 
----------             -------------          ---------         
26.02.2013 05:56:50    26.02.2013 05:57:02   00:00:12
26.02.2013 06:04:44    26.02.2013 06:05:36   00:00:52
```

Sql Code :

```
SELECT 
Int(Inbounddatum1) AS DATUM,
Format(SUM(IIf((DatePart('h',Inbounddatum2)>5 And DatePart('h',Inbounddatum2)<14),Timeinterval,0)),"hh:nn:ss") AS FRUHLEERZEIT, 
Format(SUM(IIf((DatePart('h',Inbounddatum2)>13 And DatePart('h',Inbounddatum2)<22),Timeinterval,0)),"hh:nn:ss") AS SPATLEERZEIT, 
Format(SUM(IIf((DatePart('h',Inbounddatum2)>24 And DatePart('h',Inbounddatum2)<6),Timeinterval,0)),"hh:nn:ss") AS NACHTLEERZEIT,
Format(Sum(Timeinterval),"hh:nn:ss") AS GESAMTLEERZEIT INTO LEERZEIT
FROM SUBINBINDOLEER
GROUP BY Int(Inbounddatum1);
```

Result:

```
 DATUM      FRUHLEERZEIT  SPATLEERZEIT   NACHTLEERZEIT  GESAMTLEERZEIT
 ---------  ------------  -----------   --------------  --------------
 26.02.2013 00:00:52                     00:00:12
```

Comment: persons_in_time<10:01+day and person_out_time > 5:59 +(day+1).

Comment: Since +day is not recognized by Access, I couldn't manage to solve it.

Comment: i mean +day is a variable i juz given the idea not the code. make it in a loop with the variable. Hope u got it.